# Running sp_spaceused on specific tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select query that selects certain tables from my database. I want to run `sp_spaceused` on those selected tables.

I am able to find the space used by a single table using `exec sp_spaceused table_name` But I cannot hardcode the table names in this way since the tables whose size I need to find changes daily.

Ideally what I want to do is of the below nature.

```
exec sp_spaceused(select table_name from information_schema where table_name in xyz conditions)
```

I read answers on stackoverflow but all of them talk about using `sp_spaceused` to find the size of all the tables in the database and I am not sure how to go from those answers to finding space used by **specific** tables in the way I described.

Comment: You can write a strored procedure around `sp_spaceused`, see: [Determining space used for all tables in a SQL Server database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1177/determining-space-used-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database/)

Comment: Follow / read the duplicate link in your previous post. The marked answer does exactly this. You just need to filter it as needed for the tables of interest. That query already has `WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' ` - just change it to match your "xyz conditions"